# How to lock screen and force re-login after certain period of inactivity in various flavor of linux?

Tags: linux

I want to enable the lock screen after certain period of inactivity. Once user wants to use the system again he should be forced to re-login with password.

If there is a unique solution for various flavor of linux then it is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

In various flavor of Linux this functionality is there by default for security reasons.

Though you can reduce the time for auto locking or you can disable this feature of auto-log-in.

to see how to reduce auto log-n visit this question.
[How can I change the time before the system locks?](https://superuser.com/questions/267637/how-can-i-change-the-time-before-the-system-locks)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have come across the above post earlier but it is mostly related to GUI, could you please suggest how to achieve it from the command line or a script. I have tried gsettings but it is not working on all distros. I am looking for a common solution for this if possible.

Comment: then this might be helpful for you http://xmodulo.com/control-screen-lock-settings-linux-desktop.html